# How to customize score in a solr 7.7 query using the DisMax parser

Tags: solr

I made a Solr Dismax query in a single field but searching multiple words. In the results list, I have the best matching answer with the higher score (which is good), but I also have in 2nd and 3rd position less good solutions with the same higher score, which is a problem for me.
I have read that using the tie parameter (value 1.0), it is possible to allow the score to be calculated with the matching score of all the words and not only the highest matching score.
But I cannot see any difference.
Below is the query and the answer I received. Can you help me, please ?

{
"responseHeader":{
"status":0,
"QTime":2,
"params":{
"q":"Sig_t:RxUA SRGAÇAL 2 2565140 CARVOEIRA TVD PORTUGAL",
"tie":"1.0",
"defType":"dismax",
"df":"Sig_t",
"qf":"Sig_t",
"fl":"Sig_t,score",
"debugQuery":"on",
"_":"1707919952551"}},
"response":{"numFound":4323043,"start":0,"maxScore":26.345957,"docs":[
{
"Sig_t":"RUA **SARGACAL** 2 2565140 CARVOEIRA TVD PORTUGAL",
"score":**26.345957**},
{
"Sig_t":"RUA **ARROTEIA** 2 2565140 CARVOEIRA TVD PORTUGAL",
"score":**26.345957**},
{
"Sig_t":"RUA **SALGUEIRAIS** 2 2565140 CARVOEIRA TVD PORTUGAL",
"score":**26.345957**},
{
"Sig_t":"RUA TAIPAS 2 2565140 CARVOEIRA TVD CARREIRAS PORTUGAL",
"score":24.5392},
{
"Sig_t":"RUA CAMPO DA BOLA 2 2565140 CARVOEIRA TVD PORTUGAL",
"score":22.964348},
{
"Sig_t":"RUA SARGACAL 11 2565140 CARVOEIRA TVD PORTUGAL",
"score":22.871136},
{
"Sig_t":"RUA SARGACAL 13 2565140 CARVOEIRA TVD PORTUGAL",
"score":22.871136},
{
"Sig_t":"RUA SARGACAL 19 2565140 CARVOEIRA TVD PORTUGAL",
"score":22.871136},
{
"Sig_t":"RUA SARGACAL 21 2565140 CARVOEIRA TVD PORTUGAL",
"score":22.871136},
{
"Sig_t":"RUA SARGACAL 23 2565140 CARVOEIRA TVD PORTUGAL",
"score":22.871136}]
}
}

I tried using the tie parameter.
I expected different scores for the 3 first results.

Comment: I'm guessing none text strings of those match what has been indexed after analysis, so only the `RUA` and the other parts of the search query matches (i.e. `SRGAÇAL` does not match anything - the rest of the terms are the same, so the score is the same). There is also no need to prefix the field name for one of the words if you're already using `qf` with the same field. (in this case the behavior is the same, but otherwise `RUA` would be searched against in the `Sig_t` field, while the other terms would use the `qf` setting.

Comment: You'll have to add some sort of field/values/etc. that express _why_ a hit in something else / which parts are better. Since they match the same tokens and the same token count, their scores will be identical.